# How do I get the memory cache in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, system

I have searched around a lot but not really found anything. I need the memory cache (on the picture 522 MB).
How do I get this value, can someone help me?[Screenshot of cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIZXm.png)

Can i access this via "Win32_OperatingSystem"?`

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Those values come from Performance Counters which are are available through WMI. .NET has a [PerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class that makes reading easier. [This doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-performance-information) lists the available memory perf counters and how they're combined to generate the values shown in Task Manager

Comment: From the doc page, the Cached value comes from these performance counters `Cache Bytes + Modified Page List Bytes + Standby Cache Reserve Bytes + Standby Cache Normal Priority Bytes + Standby Cache Code Bytes`

Comment: I know how I can get Cache Bytes, but how do I get "Modified Page List Bytes"?

Comment: All these are performance counter names in the `Memory` category. `Modified Page List Bytes` is a counter in the `Memory` category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation of [@Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) solution from comments (Program prints values in GB):

```
PerformanceCounter counter1 = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Cache Bytes");
PerformanceCounter counter2 = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Modified Page List Bytes");
PerformanceCounter counter3 = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Standby Cache Reserve Bytes");
PerformanceCounter counter4 = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Standby Cache Normal Priority Bytes");
PerformanceCounter counter5 = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Standby Cache Core Bytes");
while (true)
{
    Console.Clear();
    long bytes = counter1.NextSample().RawValue +
        counter2.NextSample().RawValue +
        counter3.NextSample().RawValue +
        counter4.NextSample().RawValue +
        counter5.NextSample().RawValue;
    Console.WriteLine(bytes / 1024f / 1024f / 1024f);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

The only issue is that when I try to create the counter for `Standby Cache Code Bytes`, the exception throws, saying that there is no such counter called `Standby Cache Code Bytes`. So I found a counter named `Standby Cache Core Bytes` and assumed that it might be just a typo in docs.

The description for `Standby Cache Core Bytes` is:

> Standby Cache Core Bytes is the amount of physical memory, in bytes,
> that is assigned to the core standby cache page lists. This memory
> contains cached data and code that is not actively in use by
> processes, the system and the system cache. It is immediately
> available for allocation to a process or for system use. If the system
> runs out of available free and zero memory, memory on lower priority
> standby cache page lists will be repurposed before memory on higher
> priority standby cache page lists.